# Recommended Firebase data structure for my react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a medical booking app in react native I almost done my UI and now I stuck in data structure in firebase. so the way app works is simple: user register/sign in select the doctor or the therapist and that therapist has some dates and times which user should choose from to set an appointment.

so the way I consider to structure my data is the following:

[image]

but I need a simpler approach so I can get all my dates as an array and feed my calendar with it (so user could see the available dates)
and also get all the timings for specific day so when a user select a time other users can't select that too.
how can I structure this data in firebase? sorry I'm new to this concepts if you feel this question is dumb and I'm thankful for any help.
if you need any extra information just let me know in comment section.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider extractimg meetings to its own collection and using the dates as the id of each document.. So whenever someone wants to book a meeting, you check if there is a document with the ID of the date, and if not, create the meeting

Comment: When I say use the date as the id, I meant find a way to generate a unique string for each date.. You can use the milliseconds to get the ms since epoch, and convert that to a string.. That should be unique for each time

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your suggest. I need a way to separate each date or meeting depend on the therapist so if I create another collection just for the meetings that's make my work harder. dates are related to the therapists so other therapists has their own dates.

Comment: Ok, since the dates are all related to the therapist, you can create a meeting sub collection under each therapist, that follows what I said earlier about the dates

Comment: However I usually advice against subcollections as they can easily get estranged.. If a therapist document is deleted, it doesn't automatically delete it's meetings(subcollections). So make sure to watch out for some of subcollections quarks

Comment: Hey Kevin, you seem to be giving recommendations based on Cloud Firestore, while OP is using Realtime Database. That said, the recommendation against nesting actually applies more on Realtime Database than on Cloud Firestore, and is even documented in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data

Comment: Oh, I must have missed that.. Since it is in rtdb, nesting is highly encouraged